# Prove that the degree of the splitting field of $x^p-1$ is $p-1$ if $p$ is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I came across this question I couldn't figure out how to solve:

> If $p$ is a prime number, prove that the splitting field over $F$, the field of rational numbers, of the polynomial $x^p-1$ is of degree $p-1$.

Here's what I have so far. Denote $f(x) = x^p-1 \in F[x]$. Then, $f(x)$ can be written as the product of two irreducible polynomials, namely $(x-1)(x^{p-1}+\cdots+x+1)$. If we call this latter polynomial $q(x)$, we easily see that $\deg q(x) = p-1$. If $\alpha$ is a root of $q(x)$, then $\alpha$ is algebraic of degree $p-1$ over $F$. Thus, $[F(\alpha):F]=p-1$.

I think I now need to consider the splitting field of $q(x)$, but I'm not sure exactly how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use the theory of cyclotomic polynomials?

Comment: You know that $[F(\alpha):F]=p-1$, and you also know that $F(\alpha)$ is contained in the splitting field of $x^p-1$ (equivalently, of $q(x)$) over $F$. On the other hand, it's supposed to be true that the degree of the splitting field over $F$ equals $p-1$. So for that to work out, it had better be the case that the splitting field is exactly $F(\alpha)$ - in other words, that $x^p-1$ already splits in $F(\alpha)$. Can you show that? Hint: what are the complex roots of $x^p-1$?

Comment: We can write the roots of $x^p-1$ as $1, -\sqrt[p]{-1}, (-1)^{2/p},-(-1)^{3/p},\cdots (-1)^{p-1/p}$. I'm still not sure where to go from here though.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention you in the comment @GregMartin.

Comment: @IanColey At this stage of the book, cyclotomic polynomial theory hasn't been introduced. I believe I'm only supposed to use knowledge of field extensions and roots of polynomials.

Comment: Good, so you know the roots of $x^p-1$ (other than $1$ itself) are $e^{2\pi i\cdot1/p}$, $e^{2\pi i\cdot2/p}$, ..., $e^{2\pi i\cdot(p-1)/p}$. Suppose for a moment that $\alpha=e^{2\pi i\cdot1/p}$. Can you show that all the other roots are in $F(\alpha)$, that is, that all the other roots are polynomial expressions in $\alpha$?

Comment: @GregMartin Let's see. The root 1 is trivially in $F(\alpha)$. For the others, we can express them as $\alpha, \alpha^2,\cdots,\alpha^{p-1}$. If these roots are all in $F(\alpha)$, then the splitting field, say $E$, would exactly equal $F(\alpha)$. Is this (somewhat) correct?

Comment: That's totally correct! That should finish the proof, as long as you pick your initial root to be $\alpha=e^{2\pi i/p}$. Although you can make this argument work with any $\alpha=e^{2\pi i k/p}$ $(1\le k\le p-1)$, for that matter.

Comment: I'd encourage you to post a solution to your problem, and then after some time you can accept your own solution. Helps clear up the Unsolved Problems list.

Comment: @GregMartin Great! Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sure, I'll do that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exactly following the comments above, we have the following solution:

We know that $F(\alpha) \subset E$, the splitting field of $x^p-1$ over $F$. Since $[F(\alpha):F]=p-1$, and we want $[E:F]=p-1$, it is enough to show that $F(\alpha)=E$.

If we consider the roots of $q(x)$, we have $ e^{2\pi i \cdot 1/p}, e^{2\pi i  \cdot 2/p}, \cdots, e^{2 \pi i \cdot p-1/p}$. Suppose that we take $\alpha = e^{2\pi i \cdot 1/p}$ as a root. Then, we can represent $F(\alpha) = \alpha, \alpha^2, \cdots, \alpha^{p-1}$. Note that 1, the root of $x-1$, is trivially in $F(\alpha)$. Thus, all of the roots of $f(x)$ are contained in $F(\alpha)$, so it must be the case that the splitting field $E=F(\alpha)$.