# Prove that the splitting field of $X^n - 1$ has degree $\phi(n)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Prove that the splitting field of $X^n - 1$ has degree $\phi(n)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, where $\phi(n)$ denotes the number of integeres which are less than n and are co-prime to n.

I understand that the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is the primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity.

I am not able to proceed further. In case $n$ is a prime it is clear from the answer below

[Prove that the degree of the splitting field of $x^p-1$ is $p-1$ if $p$ is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/665099)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows because the irreducible polynomial of $n$th roots of unity is
$$ \prod_{d\mid n}(X^d-1)^{\mu(n/d)}$$
(e.g., by the principle if inclusion/exclusion: $X^n-1$ has *all* $n$th roots, for $p\mid n$, you divide out $X^{n/p}-1$ to remove roots that are already $n/d$th roots; but that removes $n/(p_1p_2)$th roots twice, hence you multiply back with $X^{n/(p_1p_2)}-1$, etc.).

Hence its degree is
$$ \sum_{d\mid n}\mu(n/d)d=\phi(n).$$

Comment: I thinks $$ n\frac{\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)}{d}=\phi(n).$$